# Chrome 62 javascript modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, es6-modules

I import modules like that:

```
<script type="module">
    import mod_test from '../classes/mod_test.js';
    window.mod_test= mod_test;  
</script>
```

But Chrome says sometimes if i call a function `window.mod_test.test();`

> cannot read property 'test' of undefined

which is called in a Jquery synchronous request.

What am i doing wrong? Or it is a bug with chrome, because it happens only sometimes?

The module looks like that

```
var mod_test = {
    a: null,
    test: function (b) {
         this.a=b;
    }
};

export default mod_test;
```

Comment: Could you show also your `mod_test.js`? how do you export `mod_test` from it?

Comment: Ok, do you see `Script has been blocked by CORS policy` error right after `cannot read property` error?

Comment: no I dont see it in logs...

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no CORS issue, I think that the problem could be in a race condition between module loading and module exported fuction calling. To be sure you may try following approach. Define the app runner before the module loader:

```
<script>
  window.runTheApp = function(mod_test) {
    mod_test.test();
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

and then load your module with the app runner call:

```
<script type="module">
    import mod_test from '../classes/mod_test.js';
    window.runTheApp(mod_test);
</script>
```

Also, the [dynamic import](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) could be useful. For me it makes the approach more clear:

```
<script type="module">
  import('../classes/mod_test.js')
  .then(function(module) {
    console.log('module loaded');
    window.runTheApp(module.default);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Same fault, but i noticed if i reload with Strg+F5 or location.reload(true) it works. meta tag in HTML without creating a cache won't work too....

Comment: @crak I added log to the module loader, do you see "module loaded" message right before "cannot read property" error in the console?